Question on Ward Identities and on Noether's theorem
I am reading Polchinski's book on string theory (vol. 1), Chap. 2 subchapter "Ward identities and Noether's current".
At some point, in Eq. (2.3.12), the author claims that under spacetime translations, $\delta X^{\mu}=\epsilon \rho(\sigma)a^{\mu}$, the action varies according to
$$\delta S=\frac{\epsilon a_{\mu}}{2\pi\alpha'}
\int d^2\sigma\ \partial^aX^{\mu}\partial_a\rho(\sigma)\tag{2.3.12}$$
because the variation reduces to zero when $\rho(\sigma)$ is constant. From that, he defines the conserved current to be $$j^{\mu}_a=\frac{i}{\alpha'}\partial_aX^{\mu}\tag{2.3.13}.$$
Then, he tries to do the same with worldsheet translations $\delta\sigma^a=\epsilon\upsilon^a$, under which $\delta X^{\mu}=-\epsilon\upsilon^a\partial_a X^{\mu}$, and he writes down the conserved current (without writing down the variation of the action) as
$$j_a=i\upsilon^bT_{ab},\quad T_{ab}=-\frac{1}{\alpha'}
:\Big(
\partial_aX^{\mu}\partial_bX_{\mu}-
\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ab}\partial_cX^{\mu}\partial^cX_{\mu}
\Big):\tag{2.3.15}$$
I guess that first, the author considers a worldsheet translation that is not local and says that if that is a symmetry, then $\delta S=0$, and if it is not local, i.e. $\rho=\rho(\sigma)$, then the transformations become $\delta\sigma^a=\epsilon\upsilon^a\rho(\sigma)$, and hence the fields transforms as $\delta X^{\mu}=-\epsilon\upsilon^a\partial_a X^{\mu}\rho(\sigma)$.
If my guessings are correct, what is the variation of the action and how do we "read off" the worldsheet energy momentum tensor components from this action variation?

Polchinski is essentially relying On a trick to derive the Noether current.

Hi @Qmechanic and thanks for the comment. My question is, then, "how to apply this trick such that I obtain the form of $T_{ab}$"?
